# Data output , ds18b20 , lcd1602 , yl-69, dht11

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, c++, temperature-sensor, data

Good afternoon, I wonder if you could help me. I have the code but the data from the sensors is not correct. Perhaps there are some errors, could you fix them?

I apologise for my inaccurate statement. I have the task of displaying data from three sensors on the screen. I've written a sketch, but it doesn't work correctly. That is, the data from two sensors (ds18b20, yl-69) is not displayed correctly. I think the problem is with the sketch.
The data from sensor ds18b20 is constantly displayed differently, and partly depends on the data from sensor yl-69, although it should not. All sensors should work separately from each other, but give their data to the arduino

```
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DS18B20.h>

#include <Wire.h>                          
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>              
        
#include <DHT.h>    

const uint8_t ds1Pin{7};            // DS18b20 будем подключать к пину D7
const uint32_t msRepTime {10000};   // DS18b20 будем опрашивать каждые 10 секунд (по факту каждые 11)
uint32_t msTemp {msRepTime};        // Объявляем счетчик для опроса DS18b20 и инициализируем его значением для моментального начала процедуры
const uint8_t simvol[8] = {B11100,B10100,B11100,B00000,B00000,B00000,B00000,B00000}; 
uint8_t ds1Qty {1};                 // Количество датчиков DS18b20 на пине (не более 3-х). Если больше одного, значения будут усредняться 
int8_t  ds1Temp {0};                // Собственно, значение температуры по Цельсию от DS18b20
uint8_t ds1DS[3][8];                // Адреса положу пока здесь. Если кому не лень, их нужно убрать из глобальной ОВ, как и количество датчиков

const uint8_t DHTPin{8};            // DHT будем подключать к пину D8
float dhtTemp {0};                  // DHT значение температуры
float dhtHum {0};                   // DHT значение влажности
const uint32_t msDhtTime {5017};    // DHT будем опрашивать каждые 5+ секунд. "Кривое" значение, чтобы не пересекаться по времени с опросом DS
uint32_t msDht {msDhtTime};         // Объявляем счетчик для опроса DHT и инициализируем его значением для моментального начала процедуры

const uint8_t ylPin{14};            // YL будем подключать к пину A0(14). ВНИМАНИЕ: подключение аналогового выхода датчика!
uint16_t ylVal{0};                  // Переменная для показаний датчика влажности YL
const uint32_t msYlTime {100};      // YL будем опрашивать каждые 0.1 секунд, чтобы МК хоть чем-то был занят в цикле))
uint32_t msYl {0};                  // Объявляем счетчик для опроса YL-69

const uint32_t msPageExpo {5000};   // Устанавливаем по 5 секунд на отображение каждой страницы
uint32_t msPage {0};                // Объявили счетчик для экрана 


LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);           
DHT dht(DHTPin, DHT11);
OneWire oneWire(DS18B20);




void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);     // Скорость должна соответствовать настройкам монитора порта 
  lcd.init();               
  lcd.backlight();
  dht.begin();
  searchSensors();          // Запускаем первоначальный поиск датчиков DS18b20 на пине
}

void loop() {
  
  if (millis() - msTemp > msRepTime)  updateTemp();       // Опрашиваем температуру DS18b20 с частотой msRepTime
  if (millis() - msDht > msDhtTime)   runDht();           // Опрашиваем DHT
  if (millis() - msYl > msYlTime)     runYl();            // Опрашиваем YL-69
  if (millis() - msPage > msPageExpo) updatePage();       // Листаем страницы
  
}





//**************  Секция экранчег  ****************************
void updatePage(){                       // Листаем страницы на экранчике
  static uint8_t page {0};              
//  Первая страница
  if (page == 0){
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("temp water:    ");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print((int8_t)ds1Temp);
    lcd.setCursor(3,1);
    lcd.print("C   ");
    msPage = millis(); 
    page++; 
    return;
  }
//  Вторая страница
  if (page == 1){
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("temp air:         ");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print((int8_t)dhtTemp);
    lcd.setCursor(2,1);
    lcd.print("C   ");    
    msPage = millis(); 
    page++; 
    return;
  }
//  Третья страница
  if (page == 2){
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("hum air:         ");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print((uint8_t)dhtHum);
    lcd.setCursor(2,1);
    lcd.print("%   ");    
    msPage = millis(); 
    page++; 
    return;
  }
// Последняя страница
  if (page == 3){  
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("hum earth:         ");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print((uint16_t)ylVal);
    lcd.setCursor(3,1);
    lcd.print("%   ");      
    msPage = millis(); 
    page = 0; 
    return;
  }
}


//**************  Секция YL-69  ****************************
void runYl(void){
  ylVal = analogRead(ylPin);; //Измеряем влажность. Маппинг пишем сами, если надо
  msYl = millis();
}


//**************  Секция DHT  ****************************
void runDht(void){
  dhtHum = dht.readHumidity();          //Измеряем влажность
  dhtTemp = dht.readTemperature();      //Измеряем температуру
  msDht = millis();
}

//**************  Секция DS18b20  ****************************
void updateTemp(){                       // Основная процедура обновления температурных данных со всех датчиков
  static uint8_t stage {0};
//  Первый этап. Отправка запросов на конвертацию 
  if (stage == 0){
    if (ds1Qty) requestSensor(ds1Pin);
    stage++; 
    msTemp = millis() - msRepTime + 800;    // 0.75 секунды требуется датчику для осуществления конвертации на максимальном разрешении
    return;
  }
// Второй этап. Чтение показаний  
  if (stage == 1){  
    if (ds1Qty) readSensor(&ds1Temp, ds1Pin, ds1DS, ds1Qty);
    msTemp = millis(); 
    stage = 0; 
    return;
  }
}

void readSensor(int8_t* t, uint8_t pin, void* buf, uint8_t qt){       // Чтение температуры с датчика ds18b20
  OneWire ds(pin);
  uint8_t addr[8];
  uint8_t data[9];
  float temp[3];
  uint8_t qty {0};
  for (uint8_t c {0}; c < qt; c++){
    for(uint8_t i {0}; i<8 ;i++) addr[i] = *((uint8_t*)buf+c*8+i);
    ds.reset(); ds.select(addr); ds.write(0xBE); 
    for (uint8_t d {0}; d<9; d++) data[d] = ds.read();    
    int16_t raw = (data[1] << 8) | data[0];
    raw = raw & ~1;
    temp[qty++] = raw / 16.0;  
  }
  float tmp {0};
  for (uint8_t i {0}; i<qty; i++) tmp+= temp[i];
  *t = round(tmp/qty);
  Serial.print("Температура пин "); Serial.print(pin); Serial.print(" : "); Serial.println(*t);
}

void requestSensor(uint8_t pin){          // Отправка запроса на конвертацию ds18b20
  OneWire ds(pin);
  ds.reset();
  ds.skip();
  ds.write(0x44,0);
}

void searchSensors(){                          // Поиск датчиков на всех линиях
  ds1Qty =   src(ds1DS, ds1Pin);
}

uint8_t src(void * adr, uint8_t pin){      // Вспомогательная функция для поиска на одной шине. Возвращает количество найденных датчиков
  if (pin == 0) return 0;
  OneWire ds(pin);
  uint8_t newAddr[8]{0};
  uint8_t count {0};
  ds.reset_search();
  delay(5);
  while (ds.search(newAddr) && count <3){
    if (ds.crc8(newAddr, 7) == newAddr[7]){
       for (uint8_t i{0}; i<8; i++) *((uint8_t*)adr + count * 8 + i) = newAddr[i];
       count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: Is the compiler giving you any errors? Then you absolutely need to include them in your question. Or is the code having unexpectedly? Then you need to describe, what you expected and how the code actually behaves. I don't really want to read a long code and searching for errors, that might or might not be there. Please test yourself and then you can provide the needed information for us to help you

Comment: Please divide your program into small chunks and test them individually. If you have figured out, which part is not working as indended, I am happy to help on that small part. Also please read: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: how do you know that data from sensors is not correct? ... what are you expecting to see? ... what are you seeing? .... which sensors are affected? .... how are the sensors connected? .... **please add all information to your question** ... `do not put in comments`